# How to configure redux-persist with redux-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I have configured redux-persist with a traditional react-redux setup like this:

```
onst persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['todos'],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

const persistor = persistStore(store);

// wrapper
const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<div>Loading...</div>} persistor={persistor}>
        {children}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

But, how can I configure it with redux-toolkit?
So far I have tried this:

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, todoreducer);
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    todos: persistedReducer,
  },
});

const persistor = persistStore(store);

// wrapper
const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<div>Loading...</div>} persistor={persistor}>
        {children}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

But, It is not working. I can't get the `todos` by  `const todos = useSelector(state => state.todos);`

it returns undefined.

Comment: That looks correct though. Can you provide a codesandbox?

Answer (score 102):

store.js

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import {combineReducers} from "redux"; 
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const reducers = combineReducers({
 //...            
});

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);


const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    middleware: [thunk]
});

export default store;
```

Index/App.js

```
import store from './app/store';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'

let persistor = persistStore(store);

    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App/>
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
```

Comment: Very nice explanation.

Comment: Just so you know, redux-thunk is already included by default when you use `configureStore` from redux toolkit so no need to include it again.

Comment: This did not work for me on reduxjs-toolkit 1.8 / redux-persist 6.0.0. Following the guide in Redux Toolkit docs ( https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist ) as recommended by @pipedreambomb worked out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69502876/4646232 says we don't need thunk as it is built in the redux toolkit.

Comment: There's no need to define thunk explicitly as it comes built in with redux toolkit.

Comment: doesnt work with next-js. Can anyone give me a guide for nextjs.

Answer (score 36):

There's now a guide in the [Redux Toolkit docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist) that will help you with this, as well as providing advice for purging the persisted state and working with [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview).

It also has some code you'll want to copy and paste to ignore the action types `react-persist` dispatches. This will stop it throwing error messages (I was getting the error `` A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `register`. `` when I ran my React Native app with Expo).

At time of writing, their code sample looks like this:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

import App from './App'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})

let persistor = persistStore(store)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 7):

in store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage,
  // if you do not want to persist this part of the state
  blacklist: ['omitedPart']
};

const reducer = combineReducers({
  cart: CartReducer,
  // not persisting this reducer
  omitedPart:OmitReducer
});
// this ensures your redux state is saved to persisted storage whenever it changes
// we pass this to the store
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
});

export default store;
```

in your root component, index.js

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";

let persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      //PersistGate delays the rendering of UI until the persisted state has been retrrieved and saved to redux
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Best solution.
For Next JS

just add redux thunk...

''export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: [thunk]
});''

Answer (score 1):

When using TypeScript with `stateReconciles` option from `persistConfig`, you need a little type shim to avoid

- a) `unknown` generic inference

```
persistReducer<unknown, AnyAction>

Argument of type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ ... }>, AnyAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<unknown, AnyAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CombinedState<{ ... }>'.ts(2345)
```

- b) circular type reference

```
const persistConfig = {
  stateReconciles: hardSet as RootState,
}

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState> // Type alias 'RootState' circularly references itself.
```

The solution is in the extracted type `CombinedState`, as follows:

```
import type { Reducer } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import * as rp from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import hardSet from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/hardSet'

import createCollectionForm from './slices/CollectionFormSlice'
import auth from './slices/AuthSlice'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  stateReconciles: hardSet as (inboundState: CombinedState) => CombinedState,
  version: 1,
}

type CombinedState = typeof rootReducer extends Reducer<infer U, any> ? U : never

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth,
  createCollectionForm,
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [rp.FLUSH, rp.REHYDRATE, rp.PAUSE, rp.PERSIST, rp.PURGE, rp.REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})

export const persistor = persistStore(store)


export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

Answer (score -4):

I just tried this with the exact similar setup and it seemed to work. If it's helpful, I'm on `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",`, `"redux-persist": "^6.0.0"`, and `"react-redux": "^7.2.1"`. HTH.