# Changing from Redux to Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to React and am trying to learn by coding.

I need some help/advice with the code, with converting this Redux store to Redux Toolkit. Here I'm using a function called *configureStore*. What is good way of changing this into using the 'configureStore' which comes from '@reduxjs/toolkit'?

This is for learning purposes.
That 'createRootReducer' comes from my reducers.js which combines

```
const createRootReducer = (history) => combineReducers({
    articles: articlesReducer,
    selection: selectionReducer,
});
```

My *store.js* file:

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { routerMiddleware } from "connected-react-router";
import createRootReducer from "./reducers";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const storeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  const store = createStore(
    createRootReducer(history),
    preloadedState,
    storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), thunk))
  );
  return store;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Note in advance:**

There is an open issue related to `connected-react-router`.

In order to get your setup to work, make sure to install `history v4.10.1` - newer versions are causing errors:

*[Uncaught Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router" #312](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/312#issuecomment-647082777)*

---

**1. Middleware updates**

The `redux-dev-tools` and `redux-thunk` are already included in redux-toolkit.

If you need to import additional middleware, you can add these in by using [`getDefaultMiddleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware).

> getDefaultMiddleware is useful if you want to add some custom middleware, but also still want to have the default middleware added as well:

So with this in mind, you can remove `redux-thunk` from your `package.json`.

---

**2. Remove `redux` imports**

You no longer need to import `createStore`, `compose`, `applyMiddleware`, `combineReducers` from `redux`. All of these are handled internally in the [`configureStore`](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#using-configurestore) API provided by `@reduxjs/toolkit`.

You can also remove `redux` from `package.json`.

---

**3. Apply args to `configureStore` from `@reduxjs/toolkit`.**

---

The updated store could look like this:

```
// IMPORTANT: be sure to install history v4.10.1
// see open issue: https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/312#issuecomment-647082777
import { createBrowserHistory, History } from "history";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  routerMiddleware,
  connectRouter,
  RouterState
} from "connected-react-router";
import selectionReducer from "./reducers/selection";
import articlesReducer from "./reducers/articles";
import todosReducer, { I_TodoState } from "./reducers/todos";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

// combineReducers will be handled internally by configureStore
const rootReducer = (history: History<any>) => ({
  articles: articlesReducer,
  selection: selectionReducer,
  todos: todosReducer,
  router: connectRouter(history)
});

const preloadedState = {};
export const store = configureStore({
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(routerMiddleware(history)),
  reducer: rootReducer(history),

  preloadedState
});
```

If you pass an object to the `reducer` param in `configureStore`, the reducers will be combined. So you no longer need to make a `rootReducer` with `combineReducers`

---

Here is a [**demo link**](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-star-5l3ri?file=/src/store.ts).

---

From your initial post, it looks like you only had three middlewares:

`__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__`, `thunk`, and `routerMiddleware`.

The errors you are seeing happen because `@redux/toolkit` is offering extra protection for correct immutability and serialization of your state. It does so by including `redux-immutable-state-invariant` in its default middleware.

Your prior setup did not have this middleware, and that's why you are only seeing these errors now. If you had `redux-immutable-state-invariant` installed, you would've seen these errors in your previous setup.

To achieve an identical setup to what you had before, you do not need to include the `defaultMiddleware`, however it would be a very good idea to go through your reducers and see why your state is not immutable and/or serializable.

Here is an identical setup to what you had before, only with `@redux/toolkit`

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { routerMiddleware, connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { rootReducer } from './reducer';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

// combineReducers will be handled internally by configureStore
const rootReducer = (history) => ({
  articles: articlesReducer,
  selection: selectionReducer,
  router: connectRouter(history)
});

const preloadedState = {};
export const store = configureStore({
  middleware: [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)],
  reducer: rootReducer(history),
  preloadedState,
});
```

It looks like the dev tools are configured already: *[Store Setup](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#store-setup)*, so I did not add them here. You should be able to still use them in your browser's developer tools.

You should look into why your current state is not immutable/serializable. It is possible there are circular references in your state, or your state is being directly mutated somewhere. This can lead to some nasty bugs down the line, because Redux only truly works if the state is immutable.

However, you can still use @redux/toolkit with your current setup.

Comment: i did exactly as you said, but getting new kind of error: 1: redux-toolkit.esm.js:301 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at trackProperties (redux-toolkit.esm.js:301) at trackProperties (redux-toolkit.esm.js:312) 2: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at trackProperties (redux-toolkit.esm.js:301) at trackProperties (redux-toolkit.esm.js:312)

Comment: my reducers and action is coded with old redux style and not redux toolkit, can it stay that wat while i converted store to using redux toolkit ?

Comment: Existing reducers and actions work with redux toolkit.

The error you posted suggests state is being mutated. The error is thrown from the `immutableStateInvariantMiddleware`. Perhaps there are circular references in your state causing infinite recursion in the middleware. It's hard for me to tell without seeing your codebase. 

You could try and see if the error goes away by changing `getDefaultMiddleware()` to `getDefaultMiddleware({ immutableCheck: false })`. If it does go away, then you should check and see where the state is being mutated. Redux state should always be immutable.

Comment: its also giving : A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload`. Value:  Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  {type: 'GET_FLOORPLAN', payload: img} 
(See https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants) 
(To allow non-serializable values see: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data)

Comment: i solved those error with this : export const store = configureStore({
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      immutableCheck: false,
      serializableCheck: false,
    }).concat(routerMiddleware(history)),

  reducer: rootReducer(history),

  preloadedState,
});    but that is not right way, is there a good way to check where the state is mutated, fast way so i can really get away with those?

Comment: You should look through the reducers and see if any state is not being copied and returned.

You can get quicker hints about the problematic state by going into your `node_modules` and putting a `console.log` where the error are i.e. inside the  `trackProperites` function. You can go into `node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js` and log out some of the parameters passed to `trackProperties`. It looks like this condition `if (!isImmutable(obj)) {` is always evaluating to true, which is sending the middleware into an infinite recursion loop.

Comment: i dont have this node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js  inside my redux folder i have dist, es, lib, src folders there is no toolkit

Comment: Maybe just command-click on `redux-toolkit.esm.js` on the error in your terminal. It will open up the file if you are using vscode.

Alternatively, in the root of the project in your terminal, you can run `find **/redux-toolkit.esm.js` to get the filepath if you're on Mac or Linux (I don't know the command for Windows).

You just need to find just looking for the `redux-toolkit.esm.js` in your `node_modules`. 

Unfortunately, it's impossible for me to know any more than this without seeing the source code. I would be just guessing at this point.

Comment: when clicking it on console it takes to this: function trackProperties(isImmutable, ignorePaths, obj, path) {
    if (ignorePaths === void 0) { ignorePaths = []; }
    if (path === void 0) { path = ""; }
    var tracked = { value: obj };
    if (!isImmutable(obj)) {
     tracked.children = {};
     for (var key in obj) {
      var childPath = path ? path + "." + key : key;
            if (ignorePaths.length && ignorePaths.indexOf(childPath) !== -1) {
continue;
}tracked.children[key] = trackProperties(isImmutable, ignorePaths, obj[key], childPath);}}
    return tracked;}

Comment: that code is in red and when hovered it gives: Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Below the `if (!isImmutable(obj))` line, it would be helpful to add a new line with `console.log(obj);`.

It seems like this `obj` is not immutable, and if you can log it you might get info on the problematic state, which would point you to the problematic reducers. The reason for this is that `trackProperties` is called recursively if this condition `!isImmutable(obj)` is `true`. Infinite recursion errors will yield `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Comment: Hey it's a bit hard for me to do this kind of debugging via StackOverflow. I made an update to my original post with some code you can use.

The key issue here is that redux toolkit is detecting problems with your state that your prior setup did not detect. See the update I posted above. I hope this helps.

Comment: one question you said 'The redux-dev-tools and redux-thunk are already included in redux-toolkit.' So why you added thunk if its already included, here your code : '  middleware: [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)],
'

Comment: So if you set the `middleware` array, you need to explicitly include all middleware that you plan to use.


From https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#middleware - "If this option is provided, it should contain all the middleware functions you want added to the store. `configureStore` will automatically pass those to `applyMiddleware`.

If not provided, `configureStore` will call `getDefaultMiddleware` and use the array of middleware functions it returns.

Comment: could you possibly add also one version with typescript in it ? would help alot

Comment: The demo link I have posted above is written in TypeScript: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-taussig-kl8jt?file=/src/store.ts

When I get some time I can send you an updated link.

Comment: with that it gives me 'Argument of type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<void>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)'

Comment: i made new question related to this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69707164/argument-of-type-dispatch-any-promisevoid-is-not-assignable-to-paramet

Comment: regards the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`: in our case the reason was that we stored an object which was too nested (firebase user). Thats why the trackProperties was calling itself over and over again