# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, types, redux-toolkit

New react developer here, i'm getting an error message which does not point to my code but it points to 'redux-toolkit.esm.js:301'
`redux-toolkit.esm.js:301

```
   Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at trackProperties (redux-toolkit.esm.js:301)
at trackProperties (redux-toolkit.esm.js:312)`
```

`redux-toolkit.esm.js:301

```
   Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at trackProperties (redux-toolkit.esm.js:301)
at trackProperties (redux-toolkit.esm.js:312)`
```

when i click that redux toolkit it shows this `function trackProperties(isImmutable, ignorePaths, obj, path) { }`

so how should i fix this if it does not point to my code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing from redux to redux toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69502147/changing-from-redux-to-redux-toolkit)

Comment: If downgrading history didn't work, I recommend you follow the issue opened on GitHub https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/312#issuecomment-647082777

Comment: @Nizar that is my own question which i commented

Comment: I know, since there's already an issue opened, it seems like this is a question that can't be rectified by the stack overflow community. You'd have to follow the progress of the package there.

Comment: now that i have converted my store.js into redux toolkit, is it compulsory to convert my reducers.js and actions.js into redux toolkit ? i think it should work like this also ? one with redux toolkit and another with older, this error is not because of this ?

Comment: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide yes you do have to change to redux-toolkit format

Comment: not sure if its compulsory, i will wait if someone have a way to fix this, could you answer this question of my friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69516125/converting-from-class-to-hooks

Comment: @Nizar could you possibly check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69516125/converting-from-class-to-hooks

Answer (score 2):

This fixed my issue, setting the middleware like so

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: appReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      thunk: true,
      immutableCheck: false,
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});
```