# Argument of type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, redux-toolkit

I'm new to the Redux Toolkit, converted my code into that and everything seems fine, but dispatching gives an error:

> Argument of type '(dispatch: any) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
>
> Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: any) => Promise' but required in type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)

This is my *store.ts* file:

[Changing from Redux to Redux Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69502147/changing-from-redux-to-redux-toolkit/69502876?noredirect=1#comment123204208_69502876)

But with TypeScript I added like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-taussig-kl8jt?file=/src/store.ts

Code where I get that error:

```js
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

const loadGraph = () => {
  if (currentSite) {
    dispatch(getFloor(currentSite.identifier)).then(() => {
      console.log("Fetched floorplan");

      dispatch(getGraph(currentSite.identifier)).then(() => {
        console.log("Fetched model", realGraph.model);

        if (currentCamera) {
          dispatch(
            changeActiveCamera(
              currentSite.identifier,
              currentCamera.identifier
            )
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I would then remove the custom `useAppDispatch` function from the codebase and use `useDispatch` from `react-redux` instead. The runtime functionality is exactly the same. updated: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-taussig-kl8jt?file=/src/App.tsx:639-650

i.e. you can just change `const dispatch = useAppDispatch();` to `const dispatch = useDispatch();` and remove `useAppDispatch` from the codebase. 

It looks like The `useAppDispatch` abstraction requires further typing to be used with asynchronous actions.

Comment: Seems like the CodeSandbox has been changed. Generally, please see https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript for the officially recommended TS types here

Comment: @DanKreiger did not need to change and remove useAppDispatch, i just edited a little bit, `  middleware: [thunk as ThunkMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)],
` and this one `export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>(); //
`