# How to transform a Redux state into Redux Persist using 'combineReducers'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I try to transform my Redux state in Redux-Persist but I don't know how to write the code because I use combineReducers.

This is how looks my store:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { usersReducer } from './users';
import { eventsReducer } from './events';

export const store = createStore(combineReducers({
    users: usersReducer,
    events: eventsReducer
}));
```

And this is how looks a store:

```
const initialState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    thisUser: []
}

export function usersReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'users/loggedIn':
            return { ...state, loggedIn: action.payload }
        case 'users/addUser':
            return { ...state, thisUser: action.payload[0] }
        case 'users/setActivated':
            return { ...state, thisUser: { ...state.thisUser, activated: action.payload } }
        case 'clearAll':
            return {
                thisUser: []
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just make changes to your code in `store.js`.

### Pre-requisite

1. Install `@reduxjs/toolkit` package

- using **npm**: `npm install @reduxjs/toolkit`
- using **yarn**: `yarn add @reduxjs/toolkit`

2. Install `redux-persist` package

- using **npm**: `npm install redux-persist`
- using **yarn**: `yarn add redux-persist`

### Changes to be made in `store.js` file

##### 1. Persist all reducers

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { usersReducer } from './users';
import { eventsReducer } from './events';
import {
  FLUSH, PAUSE,
  PERSIST, persistReducer, PURGE,
  REGISTER, REHYDRATE
} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

// combine all reducers
const reducers = combineReducers({
  users: usersReducer,
  events: eventsReducer
})

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistReducer(
    {
      key: 'root',
      storage
    },
    reducers
  ),
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER]
    }
  })
})
```

##### 3. Persist only certain reducer

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { usersReducer } from './users';
import { eventsReducer } from './events';
import {
  FLUSH, PAUSE,
  PERSIST, persistReducer, PURGE,
  REGISTER, REHYDRATE
} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

// combine all reducers
const reducers = combineReducers({
  users: persistReducer(
    {
      key: 'users',
      storage
    },
    usersReducer
  ),
  events: eventsReducer
})

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER]
    }
  })
})
```

Here are the references:

- [redux-persist package npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist)
- [configure redux-persist with redux toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63761763/how-to-configure-redux-persist-with-redux-toolkit)